Jordan measurability of a subset of the domain of a continuous function
Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a closed box and let $f:B\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. I'm trying to prove that the set $\Gamma_f^{+}=\{(x,t)\,|\, 0\leq t\leq f(x)\}$ is Jordan measurable. My idea for a proof relies on the Jordan measurability of the set $D_f^{+}=\{x\in B\,|\, f(x)\geq 0\}$, but I have not been able to prove that $D_f^{+}$ is in fact Jordan measurable. So my question is the following:
Is $D_f^{+}$ Jordan measurable?
If so, any hints at a proof would be highly appreciated.
